# iPhone, How do I get a double out of my NSDictionary Array?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Heres my array

```
NSMutableArray *arrayTmp= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I populate it like this

```
double price = sqlite3_column_double(stm, 3);   
double accumPrice = sqlite3_column_double(stm, 4);

[arrayTmp addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:desc,@"desc",
    due,@"due", price,@"price", accumPrice,@"accum",nil]];
```

I assign it to a variable for use in my UITableView

```
self.transactionsArray = arrayTmp;
[arrayTmp release];
```

Which in my h file is a NSMutableArray

```
    NSMutableArray *transactionsArray;
```

Now in my CellForRowAtIndexPath I can call strings but I can't pull out doubles.

```
double price = [[[transactionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"] doubleValue];
double accum = [[[transactionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"accum"] doubleValue];
```

I've tried doubleForKey instead of objectForKey, but the compiler doesn't like that and DoubleValue but that doesn't work either.

Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to store your doubles as NSNumber instances e.g.

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:somevalue];
```

Comment: Yep, just like this: `[arrayTmp addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...[NSNumber numberWithDouble:price], @"price" ...]` and to get value from dictionary: `double price = [[[arrayTmp objectAtIndex:...] objectForKey:@"price"] doubleValue];`

Comment: Do you mean when I add them to arrayTmp or when I extract them in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Do you have any information on why this is the case? I was under the impression that `id` was the base class of all other types?

Comment: 4.5 years on and this was very helpful.  Thanks!